# Date format pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Setting format for the date

```
@String.Format("{0:D}", Model.Date)
```

Code above shows the date in the following format:   (13 January 2012)

The required output: (Friday 13 January 2012)

Is there a format for this pattern?

Comment: Documentation for formatting dates:
[Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and
[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, here you go.

```
String.Format("{0:dddd d MMMM yyyy}", Model.Date)
```

[Full MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

The general rule I use to remember these formats is like this:

one character means the number alone;
two characters means add a leading zero if necessary
three characters means use three letters if day or month, four numbers for year
four letters means use full word for day or month
Extra stuff (not special characters) just gets put in the string

e.g. Consider 1st Jan 2001

`String.Format("{0:(d;dd;ddd;dddd),(M;MM;MMM;MMMM),(y,yy,yyy,yyyy)}", DateTime.Parse("2001/01/01"))`

will return

`(1;01;Mon;Monday),(1;01;Jan;January),(1,01,2001,2001)`

Similar rules for times, like this:

```
String.Format("{0:(h;hh):(m;mm):(s,ss) (t,tt)}", DateTime.Now)
```

to give this:

```
(9;09):(41;41):(34,34) (P,PM)
```

Comment: Output: (Friday 13 January 2012)

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:dddd d MMMM yyyy}",now));
```

//output = Friday 13 January 2012

if you want the standard date format just use

```
Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("D"));
```

here is something I wrote real quick as well to help you in  the future if you want to see what you can to with the now.ToString() in regards to passing formats.
try this out in a Console Application to see the results.. Cheers

```
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("d"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("D"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("f"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("F"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("g"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("G"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("m"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("M"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("o"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("O"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("s"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("t"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("T"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("u"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("U"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("y"));
    Console.WriteLine(now.ToString("Y"));
    Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Dommer points out `String.Format("{0:dddd d MMMM yyyy}", Model.Date)` gives you the result you want. And [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) you'll find MSDN documentation on date and time formats.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be culturally-aware then use `Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object())`.

```
String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:D}", Model.Date);
```